# Can't convert tuple to string what can I do?

Tags: python, string, tuples

I am trying to turn to out_chars from tuple to string. However, it seems quite troublesome since there is while loop and the state defined its to be tuple. What should I do

I try def convertString but not succesful

```
out_chars = []        
string = ()
for i, char_token in enumerate(computer_response_generator):
    out_chars.append(chars[char_token])
    print(possibly_escaped_char(out_chars), end='', flush=True)
    states = forward_text(net, sess, states, relevance, vocab, chars[char_token])
    if i >= max_length: 
        break
    states = forward_text(net, sess, states, relevance, vocab, sanitize_text(vocab, "\n> "))
    states = convertTuple(states)
    string = convertTuple(out_chars)
    print(Text_to_sp(string, states))
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/Users/quanducduy/anaconda3/chatbot-rnn-master/chatbot.py", line 358, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/quanducduy/anaconda3/chatbot-rnn-master/chatbot.py", line 44, in main
    sample_main(args)
  File "/Users/quanducduy/anaconda3/chatbot-rnn-master/chatbot.py", line 92, in sample_main
    args.relevance, args.temperature, args.topn, convertTuple)
  File "/Users/quanducduy/anaconda3/chatbot-rnn-master/chatbot.py", line 169, in chatbot
    print(Text_to_sp(string, states))
  File "/Users/quanducduy/anaconda3/chatbot-rnn-master/Text_to_speech.py", line 28, in Text_to_sp
    myobj.save("welcome.mp3")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gtts/tts.py", line 249, in save
    self.write_to_fp(f)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gtts/tts.py", line 182, in write_to_fp
    text_parts = self._tokenize(self.text)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gtts/tts.py", line 144, in _tokenize
    text = text.strip()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you show us an example of what consists `out_chars` and also the function `convertTuple`. Otherwise, only wild guesses. At this point, you are passing a tuple to the `Text_to_sp`, which apparently expects a string.

Answer (score 1):

what does your tuple contains?? does it contain complex objects or simple strings numbers etc???
your problem is hard to understand from what you have posted above. but if you want o convert tuple to string you can do like this

```
 new_str = ''.join(yourtuple)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that understand your question right, but if you want to make a string from tuple, its really simple.

```
def convertTuple(tup): 
    str =  ''.join(tup) 
    return str

tuple = ('g', 'e', 'e', 'k', 's') 
str = convertTuple(tuple) 
print(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot ensure all the elements of the tuple are strings, you have to cast them.

```
''.join([str(elem) for elem in myTuple])
```